# Как вывести несколько значений через функцию explode php?

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Подскажите мне, начинающему недоспециалисту, как через функцию explode выводить несколько значений?

использую такую функцию:

```
function my_get_cat( $description ) {
  $description = explode( ' ', $description );
  return reset( $description );
}
```

Было: "платье женское белое на свадьбу".

Стало: "платье".

Она в данный момент выводит только первое слово. А как вывести два или три слова? Чтобы получилось "платье женское" или "платье женское белое"

Comment: после explode удаляются ненужные элементы массива и делается implode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

внедрите в функцию параметр, который будет обозначать, сколько слова вам требуется.

```
function my_get_cat( $description, $limit = 1 ) {
  $words = explode( ' ', $description );
  
  $result = array_slice($words, 0, $limit);
  return implode(' ', $result);
}
```

Comment: Это сработало! Большое спасибо =)

Comment: Можно понаглеть и попросить еще помочь?
Как можно эту функцию присоединить к другой, которая ищет определенное значение и, если его находит, то заменяет.
Я использую вот этот пример, он рабочий, но, как я уже и говорил, ищет только по первому слову. Все мои попытки внедрить твое решение в нее не увенчались успехом
```function nameF(){
$description = explode( ' ', $description );
  $data =  reset( $description );

if (mb_strpos($data, 'платье') !== false) {
    return 'платья';
}
    return ( array_key_exists( $data, $map ) ) ? $map[ $data ] : $data;
}```
БЛИН. Почему все в строчку?

Comment: Задай еще вопрос. В комментариях код __нечитабелен__.

Comment: @ИльяПокровский задайте отдельным вопросом. напишите что хотите сделать и что за $map там фигурирует.

Comment: @teran, попробовал написать вопрос снова =)) [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240432/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e]

Comment: @u_mulder, я попробовал задать еще один вопрос, где я как раз наглею ) Оч прошу помочь мне, если сможете. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240432/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e]

Answer (score -1):

```
$mass = explode( ' ', $description );
$description = ($mass[0].$mass[1].$mass[2]); //вернёт 3 слова
```